# Function to differentiate a polynomial in C++

Tags: c++, function

I've been trying to get this solved but without luck.
All I want to do is to differentiate a polynomial like `P(x) = 3x^3 + 2x^2 + 4x + 5`
At the end of the code, the program should evaluate this function and gives me just the answer.

The derivative of `P(x)` is `P'(x) = 3*3x^2 + 2*2x + 4*1`. If x = 1, the answer is 17. 
I just don't get that answer no matter how I alter my loop.

```
    /*
    x: value of x in the polynomial
    c: array of coefficients
    n: number of coefficients
    */
        double derivePolynomial(double x, double c[], int n) {
                double result = 0;  
                double p = 1;
                int counter = 1;

                for(int i=n-1; i>=0; i--) //backward loop
                    {
                    result = result + c[i]*p*counter;
                    counter++; // number of power
                    p = p*x;
                }

                return result;
            }



   //Output in main() looks like this

   double x=1.5;
   double coeffs[4]={3,2.2,-1,0.5};
   int numCoeffs=4;

   cout << " = " << derivePolynomial(x,coeffs,numCoeffs) << endl;
```

Comment: `result = result + c[i]*p*counter` is not raising it to a power, it's multiplying it by a factor.  See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/ if you want to raise a number to a power.

Comment: Thank you! For this function, you don't need that pow. You can just multiply x by x again. I just don't know how to get there correctly.

Comment: @RobertHarvey you loop from 0 to n, multiplying the current value by x, and adding the next term.

Comment: @Porkbutts the counter is doing something else in my mind at least. If you derive a function say 2x^4. It should be 2*4*x^3. That counter is responsible for the 4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The derivative of `x ^ n` is `n * x ^ (n - 1)`, but you are calculating something completely different.

```
double der(double x, double c[], int n)
{
    double d = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        d += pow(x, i) * c[i];
    return d;
}
```

This would work, assuming that your polinomial is in the form `c0 + c1x + c2x ^ 2 + ...`

[Demonstration, with another function that does the derivation as well.](http://ideone.com/taJ7Ac)

**Edit:** alternative solution avoiding the use of the `pow()` function, with simple summation and repeated multiplication:

```
double der2(double x, double c[], int n)
{
    double d = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        d *= x;
        d += (n - i - 1) * c[i];
    }
    return d;
}
```

[This works too.](http://ideone.com/P8Qbg3) Note that the functions that take the iterative approach (those which don't use `pow()`) expect their arguments (the coefficients) in reverse order.

Comment: Frankly, I think 'derive' is a misnomer for 'evaluate' here (derive the result of the formula, that is)

Comment: @not-sehe Not, sehe. Read the second formula in the question. It's the derivative, with respect to x, of the first one.

Comment: @not-sehe you're right. Actually I want this function to do two things. Derive the function and evaluate it. sorry for the mix-up.

Comment: @lulumink It's quite clear what you want. The solution I presented here evaluates any polynomial. If you want it to do the derivation as well, you can easily modify it so that it multiplies by `i` and raises `x` to the `i - 1`th power.

Comment: @lulumink or you can keep this function just to evaluate a polynomial and use a separate function to determine the coefficients of the derivated polynomial based on the original coefficients.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thank you! Even though I wanted to do it without help of the pow function.

Comment: @Andrei I get what you're saying. But the derived function has another form than the simply evaluated function. I'm not sure how to implement that.

Comment: @lulumink Then you can just use a loop to multiply by `x` in each iteration.

Comment: @H2CO3 weird, but the answer was correct too before wasn't it?

Comment: @H2CO3 I went through your second code without pow. I know it's right. But I still have trouble to understand the step. After going through the loop step by step, the first iteration gives 9 * 1.5 = 13.5. However, the first term 9x^2 should give 20.25. Yours only gives 13.5 after the first iteration. So one x = 1.5 is missing. Why? How does your code work exactly? An explanation would be very appreciated.

Comment: @lulumink It multiplies by x in each step. You will have that 20.25 factor implicitly after the second step.

Comment: @H2CO3 How did you think when programming? It's not very intuitive. Ok, your second code reads the array normally from left to right like this {3,2,4,5} which represents 3x^3+2x^2+4x+5. After the first loop, the code gives 0 + (4-0-1)*3 = 9. after second loop it gives: 9*1 + (4-1-1)*2 = 13. Third loop: 13*1 + (4-2-1)*4 = 17. But why the code thinks like this? It's not 3 * 3 * 1^2 + 4*4* 1^1 + 4 = 17 as I would normally think. What's the logic here?

Comment: @lulumink The logic is that the `i`th coefficient in the array is multiplied by `x` i times. This is an iterative form of the explicit formula `((((cn * x) + cn-1) * x) + ...) * x + c0`.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thank you very much for pointing out. I finally got it:)

Answer (score 1):

You need to reverse the direction of the loop. Start at 0 and go to n.

At the moment when you compute the partial sum for the n-th power p is 1. For the last one x^0 you your p will contain x^n-1 th power.

```
    double derivePolynomial(double x, double c[], int n) {
            double result = 0;  
            double p = 1;
            int counter = 1;

            for(int i=1; i<n; i++) //start with 1 because the first element is constant.
                {
                result = result + c[i]*p*counter;
                counter++; // number of power
                p = p*x;
            }

            return result;
        }
```

double x=1;
   double coeffs[4]={5,4,2,3};
   int numCoeffs=4;

cout << " = " << derivePolynomial(x,coeffs,numCoeffs) << endl;

Comment: Thank you @tomato, your answer is not right:( you have to go backwards. c[1] = the second element, it should start from c[3], I think?!

Comment: my answer is right. I stored the polynomial in such a way that x^i's coeff. is in the i position in the array.

Comment: the polynomial is P(x) = 3x^3 + 2x^2 + 4x^1 + 5x^0. And is stored so that in the position 0 the coef is 5, for 1 is 4, 2 is 2, and 3 is 3.